# Squashing together adjacent revisions

Tags: svn

If I check stuff in and some time later discover that I missed something in the checkin and add it via another physical checkin, is it possible to "squash" the subsequent checkin together with the main one so they appear as one checkin, which would correspond to one atomic unit of change?

I am looking for something equivalent to `git rebase`, then choosing the `s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit` option.

Answer (score 1):

No, Subversion has no mechanism for this. Each change to the repository is a single revision and you can't edit revisions after the fact.

You *could* do this by taking the repository offline, dumping & restoring only up to the last revision before your changes, then redo your commit the "right" way, but that would mess with everyone else using your repository and be far too much effort for whatever perceived benefit you'd get.